# Parse.com: issue when building the latest iOS SKD 1.7.2

Tags: ios, xcode, parse-platform, xcode6

When replacing the old Parse framework (1.6.3) with the new one (1.7.2), I get the build error :

```
Undefined symbols for architecture armv7:
  "_BFTaskMultipleExceptionsException", referenced from:
      ___53+[PFObject(Private) deleteAllAsync:withSessionToken:]_block_invoke226 in Parse(PFObject.o)
      ___65+[PFObject(Private) _deepSaveAsync:withCurrentUser:sessionToken:]_block_invoke319 in Parse(PFObject.o)
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture armv7
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I checked that the recommended libraries were added, I cleaned the project and relaunched XCode (v 6.1.1)

How to get rid of this error ?

Comment: Did you add the Bolts.framework to your project? It should come with the Parse SDK download